# Method of quantifying PHP7 extended methods which have different number of arguments to parent

Tags: php, extends, php-7.2, phplint

I'm upgrading a rather large codebase from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2.

There are thousands of places in the code where extended classes contain methods with different number of arguments to the parent method. 
e.g:

```
class SomeBaseClass {
    function someMethod($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
        ...
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass extends SomeBaseClass {
    function someMethod($arg1) {
      //Doesn't care about the other args, so doesn't specify them as params
    }
}
```

This causes a fatal error in PHP 7.2.

The fix is obviously to add default values for each argument.

e.g:

```
 class SomeOtherClass extends SomeBaseClass {
        function someMethod($arg1, $arg2=null, $arg3=null) {
          ...
        }
    }
```

But this requires that I know where all occurrences of this are.

I'm trying to find a way to either:

- Relax the error checking so PHP doesn't throw a fatal error when it encounters this.

OR

- Build out some kind of list which shows exactly which functions are breaking this rule.

I've run a php 7.2 linter on the entire codebase, but it didn't seem to pick up on this issue. I've not been able to find any other tools which would detect this.

Happy to fix them all manually, I just need to be sure I'm getting every single one of them. If anyone knows of an approach to identify them all it would be of huge help.

Comment: Just add default values to the parameters in the subclass: `someMethod($arg1, $arg2 = null, $arg3 = null)`

Comment: I should have specified. I know that's the fix for this. I just need to find all occurances of this code crime in the codebase. I'll update the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately, tool requests are explicitly off-topic for SO.

Comment: Updated to remove the mention of tool recommendation. I think since this is most likely solved via a script or configuration.

Comment: If you want help with a script, you have to show what you tried and explain the problem you're having with it. We're not going to design or write it for you.\

Comment: Hmm - yet, I get a PHP Fatal Error for it.

Comment: Thanks Paul. The missing 'function' keyword was just in my example, now corrected. What you've shown indicates the warning may be getting escalated to fatal error in some custom error handler in the codebase.